Makefile having a "hidden file" as the NAME target, like .test7?
This is my Makefile:
# the issue seems to be the "." in the filename, since
# if NAME = test7 the desired result is achieved!
# although, when I check the [4.9 Special Built-in Target Names][1]
# section of the GNU make command, there is nothing mentioned
# about this?

NAME        =   .test7

$(NAME):
    @echo Making $(NAME)...
    @touch $(NAME)
    @echo Done.

hello:
    @echo Hello :\)

all: $(NAME)
    @:

clean fclean:
    rm -r $(NAME)

re: fclean all
    @:

.PHONY: all clean fclean re

If I just simply run make for the 1st time, or any amount of times thereafter, the below output is shown:
Hello :)

Even thought the 1st rule is $(NAME), it is being ignored, because the value of it starts with a "." as in NAME = .test7 ?
Is this expected behaviour?
I have found the 4.9 Special Built-in Target Names section of the GNU make documentation and nothing is said about such?
If, however, I will have NAME = test7 (withouth the "." in the beginning), I will get the expected result, at 1st run:
Making .test7...
Done.

And after any other number of tries, just running make, the correct, output is shown as below:
make: '.test7' is up to date.

Any suggestions? To perhaps, fix this .test7 target to act like in the case of just NAME = test7 ?
THE SOLUTION TO THE ABOVE SEEMS TO BE:
Makefile:
NAME        =   .test7

.DEFAULT_GOAL := $(NAME)

$(NAME):
    @echo Making $(NAME)...
    @touch $(NAME)
    @echo Done.

hello:
    @echo Hello :\)

all: $(NAME)

clean fclean:
    rm -r $(NAME)

re: fclean all
    @:

.PHONY: all clean fclean re default_target

make by itself on the 1st run will output:
Making .test7...
Done.

While on subsequent runs will output:
make: '.test7' is up to date.

And make all will now output:
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.

Thank you for all who have commented! :)

@JohnBollinger thank you for your reply. I believe the link you have provided is irrelevant in this case? I have edited the question and I have added some comments too. Plus, see the newly added hello rule, which is taken as first rule to be executed, if the NAME = .test7 (if NAME = test7, without the ".", then everything is fine, as expected?)

Ok. I took the question to be how to get the same behavior from make on the second and subsequent runs as you do on the first. Even with the update, I find the question somewhat hard to follow, but I think I understand now what you're asking.

@JohnBollinger I am not looking for make to ignore a file named .test7 that already exists. On the contrary, I am looking for the opposite, to consider it, and show "make: '.test7' is up to date" if just make is run, or "make: Nothing to be done for 'all'." if make all is run? And in my Makefile example, this does not happen, since NAME = .test7 which is a "hidden file" starting with a "." ? Just by changing NAME = test7 (no "." in front of filename) will work as expected; also, the "@:" line will need to be removed for make all to display the message, as White Owl suggested in his answer.

This is expected.  See the manual:

By default, the goal is the first target in the makefile (not counting targets that start with a period).

(emphasis added).
You can specify a particular target using various methods as described in the manual.


Even thought the 1st rule is $(NAME)

Not exactly.  The target list of the first rule is expressed as $(NAME), but the list itself is made up of whatever that expands to.  It is the list itself that matters for most purposes, not the way it is expressed.

, it is being ignored, because the
value of it starts with a "." as in NAME = .test7 ?
Is this expected behaviour?

Yes and no.
What you observe is the documented behavior of GNU make:

a target starting with a period is not a default unless it also contains one or more slashes

(GNU make manual, chapter 4)
However, GNU make is taking a bit of a liberty there relative to POSIX, as POSIX does not specify special behavior for target names of that form, and it reserves only those that begin with a period followed by one or more capital letters for implementation-specific behavior.  Per POSIX, your .test7 should be an ordinary target.

Any suggestions? To perhaps, fix this .test7 target to act like in the case of just NAME = test7 ?

GNU make recognizes a special variable, .DEFAULT_GOAL, that you can use to specify the default goal.  You can make your .test7 the default goal of your makefile by adding this:
.DEFAULT_GOAL = .test7


Remove @: from the recipe - this action in the all target is what preventing printing a standard report "make: Nothing to be done for 'all'."
The @: is an empty command, but it is still a command. Target all is trying to do it after ensuring that all prerequisites are ready.
As alternative, you can move the echo Done into all:
$(NAME):
    @echo Making $(NAME)...
    @touch $(NAME)

all: $(NAME)
    @echo Done.

Then you will always have the "Done." message at the end of the make:
$ make
Making .test7...
Done.
$ make
Done.

Also, there is no need to put all and clean into .PHONY - they are there by default.

Thank you @White Owl, yes, the @: from the all rule will indeed cause no output at all. However, it is not the complete solution to this issue? I have updated the Makefile in my question to show an even better picture :)
